# Is there any way to pause the execution of a pinescript strategy

Tags: pine-script, pause

Hello guys Ive been looking for a way to code a pause within my code to separate an entry from an exit by 5s.

Can anyone tell me if its possible to do so and if theres already a builtin function for this

thank you !

I tried this code:

```
closePositionAfter(timeoutS)=>
    if strategy.opentrades > 0
    for i = 0 to strategy.opentrades-1
        if time - strategy.opentrades.entry_time(i) >= timeoutS*1000
            entry = strategy.opentrades.entry_id(i)
            strategy.close(entry, comment = str.format("Close \"{0}\" by timeout {1}s", entry, timeoutS))
            
closePositionAfter(120)
```

not working and probably me not knowing how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible to do. There is no such built-in function for this purpose.

Comment: dont you know how can I code it ?